# EF Query: How to constraint nested items

Tags: entity-framework

Please help me write a query for EF.

I have the following tables:

```
Products
 ProductId
 Name

Items
  ProductId
  Cost
```

How to select product with name 'AAA' and ONLY with items which cost equals to 100?

I wrote the following:

```
ctx.Products.Include("Items").Where(p=>p.Name == "AAA" && p.Items.Any(i=>i.Cost == 100)).FirstOrDefault()
```

but as a result I got Product with name "AAA" and with ALL items.

Thanks,
Dmitriy

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are loading all items for products. In any case, I'd try going the other way, i.e. the main query might be something like this

```
from i in items
where i.Product.Name == "AAA" && i.Cost == 100
select i
```

All these items should have the same product and you can eager load the product too if you need.

```
ctx.Items.Include("Products")
```